# How do I import a file of SQL commands to PostgreSQL?

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql, byte-order-mark

I'm running this command from PostgreSQL 9.4 on Windows 8.1:

```
psql -d dbname -f filenameincurrentdirectory.sql
```

The sql file has, for example, these commands:

```
INSERT INTO general_lookups ("name", "old_id") VALUES ('Open',  1);
INSERT INTO general_lookups ("name", "old_id") VALUES ('Closed', 2);`
```

When I run the psql command, I get this error message:

```
psql:filenameincurrentdirectory.sql:1: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ÿ_I0811a2h1"
LINE 1: ÿ_I0811a2h1 ru
```

How do I import a file of SQL commands using psql?
I have no problems utilizing pgAdmin in executing these sql files.

Comment: BOM? Please add the output of `hexdump -C the_filename.sql | head -1` to your question.

Comment: Thank you for the clue.  `hexdump` is not a built-in utility to Windows, though.

Comment: Yes, windows can be considered an empty toolbox. not intended for developers developers developers...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running SQL script through psql gives syntax errors that don't occur in PgAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547790/running-sql-script-through-psql-gives-syntax-errors-that-dont-occur-in-pgadmin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the problem does have to do with BOM, byte order marker.  The file was generated by Microsoft Access.  I opened the file in Notepad and saved it as UTF-8 instead of Unicode since Windows saves UTF-16 by default.  That got this error message:
`psql:filenameincurrentdirectory.sql:1: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ï»¿INSERT"
LINE 1: ï»¿INSERT INTO general_lookups ("name", "old_id" ) VAL...`

I then learned from another [website](http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-general/129mf2jnsh/using-psql-f-to-load-a-utf8-file) that Postgres doesn't utilize the BOM and that Notepad doesn't allow users to save without a BOM.  So I had to download Notepad++, set the encoding to UTF-8 without BOM, save the file, and then import it.  Voila!

An alternative to using Notepad++ is this little python script I wrote.  Simply pass in the file name to convert.

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as source_file:
        contents = source_file.read()

    with open(sys.argv[1], 'wb') as dest_file:
        dest_file.write(contents.decode('utf-16').encode('utf-8'))
else:
    print "Please pass in a single file name to convert."
```

Comment: Doesn't utilize the BOM ? for an 8-bit encoding the BOM makes no sense, since there is only one byte order possible.

Comment: That is the same argument that the URL I just added to the comment makes.  It makes Notepad use impossible for the sql files used by PostgreSQL.

Comment: easiest way to remove it *on a unix platform* is: `dd if=myinputfile of=myoutputfile bs=1 skip=3` (can also be piped, avoiding the creation of an intermediate output file)

Comment: Notepad is impossible to use for anything, not just SQL files ;) (SCNR)

Answer (score 2):

If your issue is BOM, Byte Order Marker, another option is sed. Also kind of nice because if BOM is not your issue it is non-destructive to you data. Download and install sed for windows:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm

The package called "Complete package, except sources" contains additional required libraries that the "Binaries" package doesn't.

Once sed is installed run this command to remove the BOM from your file:

```
sed -i '1 s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//' filenameincurrentdirectory.sql
```

Particularly useful if you file is too large for Notepad++