# PostgreSQL - using psql terminal to restore a dump - error: stdin is not a tty

Tags: postgresql, psql

On Windows 10, using psql with PostgreSQL 14 installed, I'm trying to restore a dump that is  `my_dump.sql`.
I'm on Bash terminal currently.

I'm connected to psql server and I created a new database `new_db`, then a new superuser `tobe`.

Then I tried the command `psql -d new_db < my_dump.sql` but I'm getting the error `stdin is not a tty`

I tried the solution `psql -U tobe -d new_db -f my_dump.sql` from ["stdin is not a tty" when populating Postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72657327/stdin-is-not-a-tty-when-populating-postgres-database)
because they mention the error but now I get a new error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ÿþ" LIGNE 1 : ÿþ

Are the two errors connected? Maybe the second error is only related to the command syntax. I'm not sure if I'm in the right direction.

Comment: Sounds as if the file was saved as UTF-8 **with** a BOM ("Byte Order Mark"). Try to convert it to one without a BOM. See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126061/

Comment: Thank you, I checked it with Notepad++ but it's UTF-8 (no BOM selected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
psql.exe -U tobe -d new_db -f my_dump.sql
```

Comment: @GrowyTobe: but that's the same command that you claimed to have tried in your question, where you stated it doesn't work.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: you're right, I just tested it again. For now, I don't know what was wrong.